# Tweenjs scale with bounceOut and return

Tags: javascript, canvasjs, tweenjs

I need to create a motion tween in code that scales up and back to the original size with a bounce effect.

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip).wait(200).to({scaleX:1.10,scaleY:1.10}, 1000, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
```

As far as I have got is, this scales up with bounce effect but stays at 110% and I need it to return to 100% all within the bounce effect. I can do this with a motion tween with bounce..., but need to be able to do this in code.

Comment: You can tween to 100% using `Back.easeOut` or else you will have to add a second tween after `onComplete` fires.

Comment: can you share an example using the Back.easeOut please?

Comment: Here is a sample that chains tweens to do a scale up, and then bounceOut https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/dKpPOy

Answer (score 0):

You can either chain two tweens, or use Ease.backOut to tween slightly over your target and then back.

Chaining two tweens

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: false})
  .to({scaleX: 1.2, scaleY:1.2}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
  .to({scaleX: 1.0, scaleY:1.0}, 200, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
```

Overshooting and then moving back

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle2, {loop: false})
  .to({scaleX: 1.0, scaleY:1.0}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getBackOut(3))
```

Documentation: https://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Ease.html